# How to bulk transfer JSON via MongoEngine

Tags: python, mongoengine

Trying to send a lot of data to MongoDB through MongoEngine. I start with a DataFrame that I write to JSON like this:

```
result = df.to_json(orient="index")
parsed = json.loads(result)
json_data = json.dumps(parsed, indent=4)
```

I then make it a little prettier using this:

```
json_object = json.loads(json_data)
json_formatted_str = json.dumps(json_object, indent=2)
print(json_formatted_str)
```

This is the result:

```
{
  "0": {
    "Address": " Bursvej 30 ",
    "Zip/city": "4930 Maribo",
    "Price": " 148.000kr. ",
    "Date": 1673371545635
  },
  "1": {
    "Address": " Garrdesmuttevej 20 ",
    "Zip/city": "9550 Mariager",
    "Price": " 148.000kr. ",
    "Date": 1673371545635
  },
  "2": {
    "Address": " Norrevej 21 ",
    "Zip/city": "6990 Ulfborg",
    "Price": " 150.000kr. ",
    "Date": 1673371545635
  },
```

But when i try to send it to Mongo:

```
MD = [MarketData(**data) for data in json_formatted_str]
MarketData.objects.insert(MD, load_bulk=False)
```

I get this error:
TypeError: **main**.MarketData() argument after ** must be a mapping, not str

Is there any other way to do this? I have been trying with PyMongo for several hours but gave up. Should I go back to that? Would prefer MongoEngine to be honest.

Thanks in advance

EDIT>

Dataframe

```
    Address Zip/city    Price   Date
0   Bursøvej 30, Bursø  4930 Maribo 148.000 kr. 2023-01-10 17:25:45.635483
1   Gærdesmuttevej 20   9550 Mariager   148.000 kr. 2023-01-10 17:25:45.635483
2   Nørrevej 21 6990 Ulfborg    150.000 kr. 2023-01-10 17:25:45.635483
3   Egernvænget 54  4733 Tappernøje 195.000 kr. 2023-01-10 17:25:45.635483
4   Egernvænget 56  4733 Tappernøje 195.000 kr. 2023-01-10 17:25:45.635483
```

And my schema

```
class MarketData(Document):
    #answers = DictField()
    Address = DynamicField(required=False)
    city = DynamicField(required=False)
    Price = DynamicField(required=False)
    date = DynamicField(required=False)
    
    def json(self):
        market_dict = {
            "username": self.username,
            "city": self.city,
            "Price": self.price
        }
        return json.dumps(market_dict)
```

Comment: your model object should be like this `MD = [MarketData(**data) for _, data in json_formatted_str.items()]`

Comment: `json_formatted_str` is well a string not a dictionary. Did you want to do `pandas.to_dict()` instead and skip all the formatting stuff?

Comment: @JonSG I've been scrambling different solutions together for a while now - think I just want it to work hahah. Pandas > Dict > Mongo is that what you suggest? I was thinking it had to be json for Mongo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to bypass all the conversion of this data to and from a string. To that end, let's just convert to a dictionary. Of course you could also just iterate over the rows of your dataframe as well but let's start with:

```py
MD = [
    MarketData(**data)
    for data
    in df.to_dict(orient="records")
]
```

Comment: TypeError: keywords must be strings

Comment: what does your dataframe look like raw?

Comment: Address Zip/city Price Date
0 Bursøvej 30, Bursø 4930 Maribo 148.000 kr. 2023-01-10 17:25:45.635483
1 Gærdesmuttevej 20 9550 Mariager 148.000 kr. 2023-01-10 17:25:45.635483
2 Nørrevej 21 6990 Ulfborg 150.000 kr. 2023-01-10 17:25:45.635483
3 Egernvænget 54 4733 Tappernøje 195.000 kr. 2023-01-10 17:25:45.635483
4 Egernvænget 56 4733 Tappernøje 195.000 kr. 2023-01-10 17:25:45.635483

I added it up top as well

Comment: Try it now with `orient="records"`

Comment: Thanks man! Not lying when i say I spent 4-5 hours today just on this crap going from the cloud version then localhost and trying both pymongo and mongoengine

Answer (score 1):

You should use the json object instead of the json string to insert data.
When you iterate over json string, it goes over each character in the string one by one which further, again is treated as string, and hence the error.

So, after

```
json_object = json.loads(json_data)
json_formatted_str = json.dumps(json_object, indent=2)
print(json_formatted_str)
```

instead of,

```
MD = [MarketData(**data) for data in json_formatted_str]
MarketData.objects.insert(MD, load_bulk=False)
```

try,

```
MD = [MarketData(**data) for data in json_object]
    MarketData.objects.insert(MD, load_bulk=False)
```

This should solve it.

A little more info...

**json.dumps()** ***returns a string value***

**json.loads()** ***returns a json object***

Therefore, ***json.dumps()*** is good for when you want **to print json data or write it to a file**
but when you need to perform some logic over the json data within the program, use the result from **json.loads()** as **python will interpret result from json.loads() as valid json object which could very well be a python dictionary or a python list object**.

Edit: There is still an error in the code below which i missed, sorry for that...

```
MD = [MarketData(**data) for data in json_object]
MarketData.objects.insert(MD, load_bulk=False)
```

As we are iterating over json_object, data will return only the keys for all entries in list, therefore to solve this, we must iterate over key, value pair object and create dictionary out of it, therefore correct way would be,

```
MD = [MarketData({k: v}) for k,v in json_object.items()]
MarketData.objects.insert(MD, load_bulk=False)
```

This should do the job.

Edit 2: Post the error still coming,
Try this,

```
items = [{k: v} for k,v in json_object.items()]
MD = [MarketData(**i) for i in items]
MarketData.objects.insert(MD, load_bulk=False)
```

Comment: I get the same error doing that: TypeError: __main__.MarketData() argument after ** must be a mapping, not str

Comment: @jmChrist Sorry my bad, have edited my solution to solve that. Essentially in the previous solution we were iterating over keys for each item in the json object which was a string value hence the error. The edit should do your job. Apologies for missing out on the error before.

Comment: That gives me this TypeError: Instantiating a document with positional arguments is not supported. Please use `field_name=value` keyword arguments.

Comment: @jmChrist Updated answer might solve the issue but the answer by JonSG above is more convenient and a neater solution since you're using pandas.